# A good way to format a list of variables and their values in a single line

Tags: logging, formatting, coding-style

From time to time a developer has some parameters or variables that s/he wants to write to a log line, console output, or in my case database view.

How would you format such a string to be the most readable?

Examples:

`ID=123, Name=John, Link=http://www.bestsitever.com/askjd.aspx?acz=23&345, Happy=true`

`[ID: 123], [Name: John], [Link: http://www.bestsitever.com/askjd.aspx?acz=23&345], [Happy: true]`

What would be the recommended / best practice format? I just can't get my string to be.. readable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON. A hybrid. Both quite easy to read and easy to parse.

Comment: Hybrid: In this case not the best when it comes to one case, but works pretty well for both cases.

Comment: well JSON is indeed readable, I decided to go with it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Personnally, when I have to extract and maipulate log data I do it in Microsoft Excel, so I format my log data to be able to import them easily by setting an Excel separator like `tab`, `;` or `,` to separate the different pieces. This way when I import them throught the import data from a text file, Excel create a distinct column for each part of every log line.

In my debugging logs I tend to dump a lot of informations like the URL query, all the URL/Session params, the user agent and the general error and multiple line breaks message which looks like :

```
2011-05-05T08:39:37-04:00 CRIT (2):  
Exception information : 
  ... error message
Stack trace : 
  ... full stacktrace
Query params (Zend) : 
array (
  ...
)
Query params (Full) : 
array(
    ...
)
Web browser informations : 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
```

I also tend to breakdown my debugging logs by date, this way if my debugging log reach many Kb, I know that at that particular date there is something wrong.